# Two forms same using same field and button submit

Tags: forms, button, submit

I have a bit trouble with the case:

I have two forms using same fields. 
I want to when user click button "Download", that form will submit to Download form.
If user click the button "Try Now", this form will get the data from the Download if have and submit to Try Now form.

Why i need submit two from with same fields to one a action: as you can see in the bottom of these form. i have a input hidden field "mkt_key", becasue this key will generate by maketing tool when the page loading, and every forms will have unique value for this field. So, that why i need to submit 2 forms, because it require by marketing tools to tracking.

You can look at my source at: `[here](http://jsfiddle.net/n2lose/8qVEv/)`

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to see the source code using the link you provided. I am assuming the problem is somewhat like as i mentioned below & providing solution.

you can use jquery to do it for you.

html:

```
<form id="myForm">
<input name="samefield1"/>
<input name="samefield2"/>
<input name="samefield3"/>
<input name="samefield4"/>
<input type="button" id="btn_dload" value="Download">
<input type="button" id="btn_try" value="Try Now">
</form>
```

jquery code:

```
$(function(){
 $("#btn_dload").click(function(){
var data   $("#myForm").serialize(); // this will serialize form data like 

                                 // samefield1=value1&samefield2 = value2;
    $.ajax({
      data: data,
      url: 'the download form submission url',
      type: 'post',
      success: yourcallback();
    });
     });
     $("#btn_try").click(function(){
    var data   $("#myForm").serialize(); // this will serialize form data like 
                                 // samefield1=value1&samefield2 = value2;
    $.ajax({
      data: data,
      type: 'post',
      url: 'the try now form submission url',
      success: yourcallback();
    });
     });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Totaly, Here is what i mean :
I have one form as below:

```
<div class="form">
    <form method="post" action="index.php" id="app_1065" name="app_1065">
        <input type="text" value="samefield" />
        <input type="text" value="samefield" />
        <input type="text" value="samefield" />
        <input type="text" value="samefield" />
        <!-- Key will be render when runtime and loading page -->
        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="dloadform" />

        <input type="button" id="btn_dload" value="Download">
        <input type="button" id="btn_try" value="Try Now">
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    $("#btn_dload").click(function(){
        var formDownload = $(".form").find("form:first");
        document.getElementById('mktForm_1065').submit();
        return false;
    });

    $("btn_try").click(function(){
        var formTryNow = $(".form").find("form:first");
        $(formTryNow).attr("id", "app_1160");
        $(formTryNow).attr("name", "app_1160");
        $(formTryNow).find("input[name='mkt_key']").val("tryform");
        document.getElementById('app_1160').submit();
        return false;
    }); 
</script>
```

- Explain: If user click the download form, it will submit with form id/name is app_1065, and key="download" by default.
  If user click the button try now, it will update the form with new id,name and key of try now form before submit form.

Issue: - Now the download form works normally by default. But i don't why the try now form doesn't work after update the new id, name and key.